# The problem about the eigenvalues of Metzler matrix in a special form

Tags: nonnegative-matrices

Let $G$ be a square matrix of the form
$$G=\left[   \begin{array}{cc} 
         A & B \\
      C & 0 \\
   \end{array}
\right]$$
with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, such that all entries of $B$ and $C$ as well as all non-diagonal entries of $A$ are non-negative.

Is it true that $G$ always has an eigenvalue with non-negative real part?

Comment: how can this be an upper triangular matrix if $C$ is nonzero?

Comment: It has be revised because of the Inaccurate description.

Comment: take $A=B=C=0$, then there are no positive eigenvalues, and yet $A$ is a Metzler matrix.

Comment: It would help if you defined *Metzler matrix* and *Hurwitz matrix*.